# What is the purpose of repainting the walls of an apartment?

Tags: painting, paint, repainting

I heard that in some places in US, such as NY, there are regulations of requiring repainting the walls of an apartment once in a number of years.

What is the purpose of repainting the walls of an apartment?

Does the paint prevent something unhealthy leaking from the wall, like lead?

Is the paint itself harmless to health?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> In some areas, such as rent controlled communities, there may be
>   requirements for landlords to paint rental properties. In New York
>   City, landlords must paint every three years, while in West Hollywood,
>   landlords have a four-year requirement. [[source]](http://www.rentprep.com/property-maintenance/often-landlords-paint-rental-properties/)

The implication seems to be that landlords are required to paint simply as a measure to prevent decay of the property and poor or unsanitary conditions for tenants.

[More reading](https://www.brickunderground.com/blog/2014/08/painting_faqs)

Answer (score 1):

Those particular communities are very tenant-heavy, and have very strong rent-control laws.  The upside of rent-control is preventing the people who make the city special - shopkeepers, artists, activists, etc. - from being priced out, leaving what Gertrude Stein describes as a city where **there's no *there* there.**  The downside is it reduces the funds available for profit *and upkeep too*.

There's nothing *particular* about 15-year-old apartment paint, if it's in good shape.  And if you're happy with your apartment paint, bon appetit.  *Those (and many, many other)* rules give tenants and tenants-rights organizations leverage to force slumlords to do upkeep, and (as an aside) settle the question of whether they can evict a tenant using maintenance as an excuse.

The 3-year paint rule is really about reducing the cost of litigation.  If the landlord can't show receipts, BLAM case closed, no need for each party to spend another $5000 with inspections and battling experts.  Otherwise the tenant would think twice about filing, because he'd need to explain why <3 year old paint failed already.  Smart law.